# Elegant Solution To The C++ Polymorphic Inheritance Problem

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Imagine the library that we are using has two classes Dog and Bowl

```
class Bowl;

class Dog
{
    Bowl* m_bowl;
};

class Bowl
{
    Dog* m_owner;
};
```

Dog owns a pointer to its associated Bowl object. Bowl also owns a pointer to its associated Dog object. Everything is fine. I now derive a new class FancyDog extending the functionality of Dog

```
class FancyDog : public Dog
{
     // Do the fancy dog stuff
};
```

Everything is still fine, at least until FancyDog needs to replace her boring, old plain bowl with a new shiny, luxury bowl.

```
class FancyBowl : public Bowl
{
    // Extra functions only relevant for FancyBowls
};
```

How should FancyDog interact with its new FancyBowl? I can only think of two options both of which are "fine" but neither of which feel very satisfying

1. FancyDog owns a FancyBowl pointer in addition to the Bowl pointer object she inherits via Dog. Technically they may belong to different classes but conceptually a FancyDog now holds two different pointers to the same object which doesn't make me feel like an elegant coder. If we are being pedantic we are also wasting memory, admittedly a negligible amount in most contexts.
2. FancyDog dynamic casts its Bowl pointer to a FancyBowl pointer every time it needs to access the derived interface. Perhaps the performance hit is not a big deal if we only need to do this once or twice, but again it doesn't make me feel warm and fuzzy.

Is this simply a classic performance-memory trade off or is there a more elegant solution?

P.S. Note that we will have the same problem if we attempt to make the FancyBowl keep track of the Dog.

Comment: Don't use raw pointers is the closest advice I can give.

Comment: FancyBowl is a child of Bowl. What's wrong with making any method that needs differentiation between Bowl and FancyBowl virtual? That way you only have to guarantee that FancyDog objects are constructed with/given FancyBowl pointers.

Comment: It honestly feels more like this design simply didn't get its abstraction right.

Comment: Perhaps simple inheritance doesn't model this relationship correctly. Dog could be specialized on its bowl and assume it has atleast `Bowl`'s interface.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I looked at the raw pointers but ownership/lifecycle is not the problem here.

Comment: One could simply think that you should "assert" that `FancyDog`s receive `FancyBowl`s and vice versa

Comment: One could be wrong about that. This is a type system thing and should be statically enforced if possible.

Comment: Examples of turning this kind of bad design into a good design are discussed at length in the book Design Patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue of poor design on the part of the Dog/Bowl author. Consider the following refinement:

```
class Bowl;

class Dog
{
    virtual Bowl* getBowl() = 0;
};

class Bowl
{
    Dog* m_owner;
};
```

Now an implementation of FancyDog can hold a FancyBowl and return a pointer to that no problem.

Essentially, the issue is one of variance- because the Dog class retains the right to *assign* to the `m_bowl` pointer, you can never be guaranteed that it will always point to a FancyBowl, as Dog may reassign it. In the first case, you guarantee that the FancyDog always has a FancyBowl, but you lose the guarantee that the Dog and the FancyDog see the same bowl. In the second case, you don't know that the bowl will be a FancyBowl but you know you are at least always using the same bowl.

If the Dog class declares a more minimal interface that only requires what the class actually needs (i.e. that you have a Bowl available for it to read) then the problem goes away. There are more complex static variants of the above as well if you don't like a simple runtime polymorphic getter.

Comment: Really clear explanation thanks! In my specific case it would be a lot of work to change the library but I definitely learned a lot + your name is too relevant! Any chance you have a link or search keyword for the static variant you mentioned just so that I can take a quick look and see if I can understand it?